# Set font in listings in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings

I want to set specific font just for listings in XeLaTeX.

```
\newfontfamily\consolas{Consolas}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyLanguage}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    .... % my language definition
}
\lstnewenvironment{MyLanguage}[1][]{
    \lstset{language=MyLanguage,#1}
    \consolas  % do not work
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyLanguage}[caption={....}]
...
\end{MyLanguage}
\end{document}
```

I know it is possible to set default mono-space font for whole document with

```
\setmonofont{Consolas}
```

and it is working but I do not want other mono-space things like URLs in that font.

Maybe if it is possible to set mono-space font to its default and use this

```
\lstnewenvironment{MyLanguage}[1][]{
    \lstset{language=MyLanguage,#1}
    \setmonofont{Consolas}
}
{\setmonofont{??default??}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\lstset{basicstyle=\consolas}`? Also `basicstyle=\ttfamily` should work when you declare `\setmonofont{Consolas}`.

Comment: Wow... I am amazed, `basicstyle=\consolas` really works. `basicstyle=\ttfamily` with `\setmonofont{Consolas}` was affecting other mono-spaced things like URLs which I want with normal font. Can you write your answer as real answer so i can mark it as answer? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "correct" way is to use `\setmonofont`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyLanguage}{ .... } % my language definition
\lstnewenvironment{MyLanguage}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=MyLanguage,basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
  {}
```

Should you want a specific monospaced font for only your `MyLanguage` listings, you can do

```
\newfontfamily{\consolas}{Consolas}

\lstnewenvironment{MyLanguage}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=MyLanguage,basicstyle=\consolas,#1}}
  {}
```

I'd add also the `columns=fullflexible` option, but it's a matter of taste.